# Replace link in text to this link with new img tag inside

Tags: php, preg-replace

i have some html like this

```
<span itemprop="actor" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person"><a rel="nofollow" href="/ru/name/shameik-moore" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Шамеик Мур</span></a></span>
```

and i need to insert img tag inside link before inner span tag like this

```
<span itemprop="actor" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person"><a rel="nofollow" href="/ru/name/shameik-moore" itemprop="url"><img src="/photo/00/04/20/42074.jpg"><span itemprop="name">Шамеик Мур</span></a></span>
```

im trying the php code

```
$img = '<img src="/photo/00/04/20/42074.jpg">';
$actor = preg_replace('|(<a.*?>)|', '$1'.$img, $it);
```

but in result i have this

```
<span itemprop="actor" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person"><img src="/photo/00/04/20/42074.jpg"><span itemprop="name">Шамеик Мур</span></a></span>
```

where i lost my first  tag here? )) please help with my reg_replace expression

Comment: Regex is not well suited for this task.  You should use an XML/HTML parsing library, which PHP definitely has available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.

```
$img = '<img src="/photo/00/04/20/42074.jpg">';
$actor = preg_replace('/(<a\b[^<]*>)/', '$1$img', $it);
```